# Trying to update field that use hasmany in PayloadCMS with API and postman

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, payload-cms

I tried creating a field with hasmany and tried the API update to add UserID, but it doesn't work. I made it using Vue JS and Payload CMS. what's the solution?

I can add UserID with API, not with UI(because it is possible with UI)

Comment: There isn't any actionable information in this question.  You haven't shown what "I tried creating a field" or "it doesn't work" means.  A code snippet would go a long way toward that, ideally a MCVE